# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, paramerization using DbCommand in c#

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, parameterized

I have this function to execute a parameterized select query:

```
public string LookUp(string sColuna, string sTabela, string sWhere)
{
    string[] Parameters = { "@column", "@table", "@where" };
    var comando = @"SELECT @column FROM @table WHERE @where";
    var cmd = this.OraConnection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = comando;
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters.Select(item => { var param = cmd.CreateParameter(); param.ParameterName = item; param.Value = 1; return para; }).ToArray());
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = sColuna;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = sTabela;
    cmd.Parameters[2].Value = sWhere;
    DbDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    return Reader.GetString(0);
}
```

when it reaches the `DbDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` it throws me an exception saying: Additional information: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@where'.
Can't one have a parameter in the where clause?

> Now I've changed it to:

```
var cmd = this.OraConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE", sColuna, sTabela, sWhere);
            DbDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return Reader.GetString(0);
```

Comment: A Where clause must evaluate to a Boolean expression... e.g. Where xyz = @where

Comment: Can't I have something like WHERE @something = @something?
I'm passing this to the sWhere var: UserName = 'Joao'

Comment: is `@where` contains string like `WHERE val=val` ??

Comment: @JaydipJ nope, @where contains val=val, hence I left the "WHERE" clause here ` var comando = @"SELECT @column FROM @table WHERE @where";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String sWhere`
is the parameter needed to evaluate a boolean expression

[The Begining of your Query] WHERE [Something]=[Your Parameter]
[The Begining of your Query] WHERE [Something]=@where

For @where value =  sWhere

If you want a more complexe answer about building WHERE clause, have a look at this answer [about the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118457/4461794)

Comment: ok I understand what you mean, but can't the [Something] also be a var? can it be a parameter, or it needs to be fix?

Comment: If you follow the link you 'll see that it cannot be directly a parameter as you try but you can elaborate alternative option using object as parameter for the left member of the boolean expression.  
Basicly you can construct a parametrized where clause, but not the way you try ;)

Comment: Ok I've read the answers and I acknowledge that it works but not for my case, because I can't possible now what the field name will be so I can't make it fix. all the parameters in the query can change since this is ment to work both for oracle and sql and also for a wide range of users and databases. is there any other alternatives to this?
I could just pass the command as a whole but then I wouldn't be able to parameterize. Does the select statement represents a risk in terms of sql injection?

Comment: I could just pass a string with the command like: "SELEC something FROM something WHERE something = anotherSomething"

Comment: var cmd = this.OraConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE", sColuna, sTabela, sWhere);
            DbDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return Reader.GetString(0);

Comment: What the new diagnostic? Error? Does your string.format throws exception?

Comment: I've found out that I actually need to build a dynamic query