# Filtering on two different things with DataSet

Tags: c#, filter

I can now filter on one thing (input is a `textbox`). But I want to filter on `two textboxes`. How to do this?
I'm using a `DataSet`, I added this `query` to it: `select * from question where questioncat = @questioncat`. 
In the `FillBy` i'm using this `query`.
I also want to `filter` on question `(where question = @question)`

Code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtBxSearch.Text == "") 
            {
                hR5DataSetVraagTableAdapter.Fill(hR5DataSet.question);
            }
            else
            {
                hR5DataSetVraagTableAdapter.FillBy(hR5DataSet.question, txtBxSearch.Text); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't use just use parameter to add the filter condition?

Comment: Because I need to add another textbox in my case where you can put in the question. The other textbox is for the questioncat. I want to filter on a question AND a questioncategory, at the same time

Comment: I wrote a answer hope can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to dynamic set your filter condition you can try to use condition with a parameter to make it.

Dynamically build the filter statement for the SQL query in code skipping any parameters that are empty

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var sqlStr = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sqlStr.AppendLine("select * from question where 1 = 1 ");

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBxSearch.Text)){
        sqlStr.AppendLine(" AND questioncat = @questioncat ");
         Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@questioncat", txtCondition1.Text));
        //and add parameter for your command.
    }

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBxSearch1.Text)){
        sqlStr.AppendLine(" AND questioncat1 = @questioncat1 ");
        Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@questioncat1", txtCondition2.Text));
        //and add parameter for your command.
    }
    //.... do your SQL execute.

}
```

**NOTE**

`WHERE 1 = 1` let you can set your condition with `AND` operation.

Comment: So with this solution I can also filter on two things; input in txtCondition1.Text AND txtCondition2.Text?

Comment: @DutchFatBoys Yes  you just add then in the condition

Comment: @DutchFatBoys Or you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118245/dynamic-where-clause-in-parameter